# How can I see the seed of my friend's SMP in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I want to get the seed of my friends SMP to find a slime chunk, I tried using NBTexplorer but the world wasn't there. Any ways I can get the seed (anything works)

Comment: I know you mention NBTExplorer doesn't work, but then you first need to figure out *why* the world isn't showing up, which is a completely different question. So, alternatively, this can be closed as needing details.

Comment: @Joachim this isn't his world, it's his friends which explains why none of that is working

Answer (score 1):

If you have admin permissions on the server, you can write /seed to find the seed. Otherwise, there are client-sided mods [like this one](https://github.com/KaptainWutax/SeedCracker) that can crack the seed of your friend's SMP in no time.